# Tiles2 + Struts2 xml validation

Tags: struts2

i have a problem, i have my login with Strits2, Tiles2 and Struts xml validations, when i run my webapp the first page is the login and the struts2 xml validator send me the error, how do i tell that for the first time do not validate until submit?

```
    <action name="loginPage"  class="com.webapp.login.action.LoginAction">
        <result name="input" type="tiles">loginPage</result>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">loginPage</result>
    </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to go to a "blank form", you should execute the `input()` method of your Action. This tells Struts 2 that you do not want to perform any validation for the action:

```
<action name="loginPage"  class="com.webapp.login.action.LoginAction" 
        method="input">
    <result name="input" type="tiles">loginPage</result>
    <result name="success" type="tiles">loginPage</result>
</action>
```

Then, you should submit your login form to another action definition that executes the default action `execute()`. Struts 2 will then try to perform Action validation:

```
<action name="loginPageSubmit"  class="com.webapp.login.action.LoginAction">
    <result name="input" type="tiles">loginPage</result>
    <result name="success" type="tiles">loginPage</result>
</action>
```